# Automated Way to Determine Max Column/Max Row Number for Tikz "matrix of math nodes"

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

In the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  below, I have defined

```
\def\MaxRow{3}
\def\MaxColumn{4}
```

which means that this code won't work if I happen to add a row or a column to the matrix without also adjusting the constants `\MaxRow` and `\MaxColumn`. Is there an easy way to determine

- the maximum number of rows and
- the maximum number of columns

of a `matrix of math nodes`?

In the code below I am drawing a line between the south west entry to the north east entrance.

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 

\def\MaxRow{3}
\def\MaxColumn{4}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [
        matrix of math nodes,
    ]{
            1 & 2 & 3 & a\\
            4 & 5 & 6 & b\\
            7 & 8 & 9 & c\\
    };
    %% How to determine \MaxRow and \MaxColumn here?
    \draw [red, thick, -latex](m-\MaxRow-1.south west) -- (m-1-\MaxColumn.north east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need the number or do you need a way to reference the node? Say `(m-Z-1)` and `(m-1-Z)`? We can give the nodes aliases. Will the matrices always have a node in each cell? If not, it can get tricky. Alternatively, we access the internal counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn`, maybe. Alternatively², use the corners of the matrix and subtract the inner sep of the matrix for this use case.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Number would be better as that seems more flexible. Yes they will always has a node in each cell.

Comment: Do you know the package `nicematrix`? If all you need is an `array` with a red arrow through it, it might be a better approach than a TikZ matrix.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes, I am aware of `nicematrix`.  I personally am not using it yet as I am redoing all my figures and trying to get them to compile in the first run. A `nicematrix` solution may be useful to others, so that solution is also welcome here.  The arrow through the entries is just an example used in the MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my surprise, it is as easy as using the internal counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` as they are not reset after the matrix has been constructed.

Of course, these values are only valid until the next matrix is constructed.

---

As an alternative, I've added a `matrix with last` key that sets up matrices so that after the matrix

- `<matrix name>-<row>-Z` references the last node in row `<row>`,
- `<matrix name>-Z-<column>` references the last node in column `<column>` and
- `<matrix name>-Z-Z` references the last node in the matrix.

(This applies to every node inside a cell so is not as straight forward for more complex matrices.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand*\MaxRow{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
\newcommand*\MaxColumn{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
\tikzset{
  matrix with last/.default=Z,
  matrix with last/.style={
    every matrix/.append style={
      nodes={
        alias=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-#1,
        alias=\tikzmatrixname-#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
        alias=\tikzmatrixname-#1-#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of math nodes,
  matrix with last
]{
  1 & 2 & 3 & a\\
  4 & 5 & 6 & b\\
  7 & 8 & 9 & c\\
};
\draw[red, thick, -latex](m-\MaxRow-1.south west) -- (m-1-\MaxColumn.north east);
\draw[blue, bend left] (m-Z-1.south west) to (m-1-Z.north east) to (m-Z-Z.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For information, there is a way to create such figure with `nicematrix` (and TikZ to draw the arrow).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & a \\
  4 & 5 & 6 & b \\
  7 & 8 & 9 & c 
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw [red,thick,-latex] (last-|1) -- (1-|last) ;
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]